# Does this convey "It's not surprising that ___"?

Tags: grammar, jlpt

I am working on the grammar pattern `～にはあたらない`, which is used to indicate that something is not necessary. I.e, "No need to ask"　==> `聞くにはあたらない`.

What I'm caught on is this example sentence:

> 彼女が試験に合格したからといって驚く**にはあたらない**。

It may be a subtle difference, but is this meaning closer to the English "There is no need to be surprised (that she passed the test)" or "It's not surprising (that she passed the test)"?

I ask because the former sounds almost condescending, while the latter seems praising.

I'm sorry if this is too nit-picky, or it's simply a matter of poorly worded study material.

Comment: Yes, it could be translated like your _"It's not surprising that..."_ line.

Comment: Perhaps this question should also cover the issue of what the verb あたる does?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[驚くにはあたらない](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E9%A9%9A%E3%81%8F%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AF%E3%81%82%E3%81%9F%E3%82%89%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84) means "it's not surprising that", so your second translation is correct.